# What are the ways to find the Sitecore version on Sitecore installations?

Tags: settings

For the existing Sitecore instances, what are the different ways to find the version of the Sitecore CMS ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you have access to the file system for the instance, you can look at `/sitecore/shell/sitecore.version.xml`.  Otherwise, you can log into desktop mode and from the start menu, go to `All Applications > System > License Details`.

Also sitecore output the sitecore version to new error log  files.

Comment: If you have file access you can also look at the file properties of `Sitecore.Kernel.dll`. It also states the Sitecore version (prior to v8.2). They have changed the file version number to 10.x starting from version 8.2. No idea why.

Comment: Also, if you have access to the file system - the version of Sitecore is also listed at the start of the main log file

Answer (score 4):

An alternative way to see the version and License Id on Sitecore 8+. Go to the login screen `/sitecore/login` and view the source. Search for an element Id called `licenseOptions` - you should see this:

```
<div id="licenseOptions" style="display: none;">

    <div class="license-info-wrap">
      <ul>
        <li>System information</li>
        <li>License holder YOUR NAME</li>
        <li>License ID 123456789123</li>
        <li>Sitecore version Sitecore.NET 8.1 (rev. 160519)</li>
      </ul>

      <iframe src="http://sdn.sitecore.net/startpage.aspx?..." id="StartPage" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" style="display: none; height: 105px;" onload="javascript:this.style.display=&#39;block&#39;"></iframe>

    </div>
    <div class="login-link-wrap">
      <a href="javascript:;" id="licenseOptionsBack" class="login-link">&lt; Back</a>  
    </div>

</div>
```

You can enabled this to be visible in the settings config too. Change this setting `Login.DisableLicenseInfo` to false.

Source: [Kb Article](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/432983)

Answer (score 3):

In Sitecore 7.5 and down, you can view the exact version of Sitecore from the Content Editor. Click on the Sitecore Icon in the top left hand corner, then select "About". A new dialog box will appear with the Sitecore version information

Answer (score 1):

### Control Panel

You can have the Sitecore version from the Sitecore Control Panel:

[image: Control Panel]

### Login Screen

You can also have it on the Sitecore login page for Sitecore 7.5 and earlier.

On Sitecore 8.x and other versions not using Identity Server, it is present in an hidden section on the login page, activated by setting the following value:

```
<!--  LOGIN DISABLE LICENSE INFROMATION
  If true, Sitecore hides the "License Information" link on the login page.
  Default: true
-->
<setting name="Login.DisableLicenseInfo" set:value="false" />
```

[image: Sitecore Login Screen]
[image: License Details Login Screen]

### Inspect DOM

You could also inspect the page DOM and show this section by yourself: https://grantkillian.wordpress.com/2016/04/05/how-sitecore-phones-home-maybe/

Looks for the element `<div id="licenseOptions">` and inspect the content. NOTE: In later versions of 8.2, this element is only present when the above config setting has been set to `false`.

Comment: First 2 links are broken - can you edit your answer to contain the important info?

Comment: Without the links content, I do not know that is the important info they contained. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it programmatically, it is possible to find Sitecore's  version using the following code:

```
Sitecore.Configuration.About.GetVersionNumber()
```

This is not documented, but Sitecore uses this method internally to find the version and display it in different parts on the CMS.

Comment: Kindly add more details with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the Sitecore 9 Content Editor, clicking the top left hamburger menu provides these shortcuts:

[image: license shortcut in content editor]