# Can you identify the Sitecore version from the Sitecore.Kernel.dll version?

Tags: configuration

Prior to Sitecore 8.2 the **Sitecore.Kernel.dll** version was the same as the version of the product I was using, however, from 8.2 the dll version seems to be ambiguous, like 10.0.3.309.

*Is there a way to identify the Sitecore version by dlls in the bin folder starting from 8.2?*

Comment: Maybe you can the version info from `/sitecore/shell/sitecore.version.xml`? http://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/343/135

Comment: @jammykam I am able to see this from the sitecore log as well, but the trick  is about identifying it by dll

Answer (score 30, accepted):

With Sitecore 8.2 Initial release, you could open the properties of a Sitecore.Kernel.dll, go to the Details tab, and the "Product Version" field contained the revision number (rev. 160729) that you could look up on [**this page**](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform.aspx). Unfortunately, this is no longer an option with 8.2 Update 1 and 8.2 Update 2.

So here's the mapping of the **Sitecore.Kernel.dll** versions since 8.2 that exist to date:

- 17.0.50.0 - 10.2.1 rev 01366.16252 (Update 1)
- 17.0.0.0 - 10.2 rev. 006766 (Initial Release)
- ?
- 15.0.1.0 - 10.0 rev. 004842 (Update 1)
- 15.0.0.0 - 10.0 rev. 004346 (Initial Release)
- 14.0.0.0 - 9.3 rev. 003498 (Initial Release)
- 13.0.0.0 - 9.2 rev. 002893 (Initial Release)
- 12.0.1.0 - 9.1 rev. 002459 (Update 1)
- 12.0.0.0 - 9.1 rev. 001564 (Initial Release)
- 11.1.2.461 - 9.0 rev. 180604 (Update 2)
- 11.1.1.395 - 9.0 rev. 171219 (Update 1)
- 11.1.0.369 - 9.0 rev. 171002 (Initial Release)
- 10.0.9.605 — 8.2 rev. 180406 (Update 7)
- 10.0.8.560 — 8.2 rev. 171121 (Update 6)
- 10.0.7.479 — 8.2 rev. 170728 (Update 5)
- 10.0.6.427 — 8.2 rev. 170614 (Update 4)
- 10.0.5.377 — 8.2 rev. 170407 (Update 3)
- 10.0.4.315 — 8.2 rev. 161221 (Update 2)
- 10.0.3.309 — 8.2 rev. 161115 (Update 1)
- 10.0.0.5597 — 8.2 rev. 160729 (Initial Release)

**Note:** Newer versions of Sitecore should be added to the top as they are officially released.

Comment: We can all pitch in and edit your answer as needed, right? No issue there? Hate for you to feel like the burden is all on you.

Comment: @PeteNavarra of course! As a matter of fact, this is also true for all stack exchange answers ;-)

Comment: But Wikis!  I kid I kid. =)

Comment: Sitecore updated the numbering convention for the Analytics DLL from version 4. This was always likely to happen since separate libraries can now independently be updated. Incorrect info was removed.

Answer (score 4):

Just an update for Sitecore 9, here are the Sitecore kernel dll's file versions for different releases -

- 11.1.0.369 = 9.0 rev. 171002 (9.0 Initial Release)
- 11.1.1.395 = 9.0 rev. 171219 (9.0 Update-1)
- 11.1.2.461 = 9.0 rev. 180604 (9.0 Update-2)