# How to find which version of Sitecore is used for building website from customer facing site (Delivery Website)

Tags: sitecore-client

Is there any online tool or trick to find the Sitecore version from customer facing site?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21938171/detect-whether-a-site-is-build-on-sitecore/21939101 for some inspiration

Comment: Having a list of vulnerabilities to Sitecore and a way to detect the instance version publicly could prove disastrous.

Answer (score 2):

As per my knowledge, No we can't find the Sitecore version is used for building the website from customer-facing site. The "No" here for the finding website using the browser or by visiting the website. But yes we can find the Sitecore version if we have delivery website folder by looking into the Sitecore.kernel dll version, see here for version - [Can you identify the Sitecore version from the Sitecore.Kernel.dll version?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/4358/can-you-identify-the-sitecore-version-from-the-sitecore-kernel-dll-version)

Of course, if you have access to the file system, you can look at  `/sitecore/shell/sitecore.version.xml`, or you can log into desktop mode and from the start menu, go to All Applications > System > License Details if you have access of it. There are few other ways but none of them are for the devilry website - https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/891209

Comment: Thanks Mahendra but I am specifically looking for customer facing website as CMS is not accessible. Is there any tag or any link which I can access in v8.x but not in 9.x or vice versa from which at least i can assume the version.

Comment: I don't think this is possible