# Is it possible to get Sitecore version using C#?

Tags: versions

I need to get Sitecore version inside my code. Is it possible to obtain it using C#?

Comment: Could you provide more details about your use case? Why you need to get sitecore version in code?

Comment: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/33422/277

Comment: If you want to do it programmatically, it is possible to find Sitecore's version using the following code:

Sitecore.Configuration.About.VersionInformation()